# Discord.js v14: Handling multiple simultaneous interactions

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm wondering what the best approach is for handling multiple simultaneous interactions at the same time?

For example, I have built a library of slash commands for our Discord bot. A few of them take a while to process data, others respond really quickly.

I'm not too concerned about the interactions that respond quickly because the odds of someone running a simultaneous slash command before a response is given is fairly slim, however ..

I've noticed however that when I run a slash command that takes a while to fetch a response, and then I run the same girthy slash command before the response has been given via `interaction.reply`, `interaction.editReply` or `interaction.followUp` , Discord.js seems to forget which interaction that it is meant to be replying to and throws an exception when trying to reply with a response for the first interaction.

The question is, if running multiple slash commands and handling multiple interactions at once, how would you guys go about approaching it?

I've tried to write a global flag to check when an interaction is pending, for example:

```
let interactionProcessing // Within a global scope

...


// Further down, within the slash command functionality
if(interactionProcessing) {
  return;
}

interactionProcessing = true;

// Logic here that processes the output

interaction.reply({content: theLogicsOutput}); // The issue here is, that it seems to have lost the definition for the initial interaction and throws an exception

interactionProcessing = false;

return;
```

I'm just curious to see if anyone else has encountered this issue and if they have any advice in honesty.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`deferReply`](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/14.14.1/CommandInteraction:Class#deferReply) to acknowledge to the API that your bot has received the interaction, then edit the deferred reply later once you are done:

```
await interaction.deferReply();
// Your long running task here...
await interaction.editReply({ content: "Done!" });
```

---

If your bot doesn't respond to a user's interaction within a few seconds, the API Gateway will time-out.
*(As it has assumed an error occured on your end)*

Defer reply allows you to reply to the user with a thinking state first, which you should edit afterwards.

> Also, hopefully you setup your project to use async/await, you can check the [documentation's example](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/14.14.1).